# Batch - Delete a specific file with forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I want to do `echo` only checking the date from one file with `forfiles`:

```
forfiles /m "C:\Backups\TEST.bak" /c "cmd /c echo test" /d -1
```

But it returns me an **error**:

> The System cannot find the file specified.

And that file it exists and the directory is correct.

If use `forfiles` in the same directory (without file) it works fine:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Backups" /c "cmd /c echo test" /d -1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
forfiles /p "c:\Backups" /m "test.bak" /d -1 /c "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime"
```

`/p` needs a folder to start searching

`/m` needs a file mask to indicate what to search

Comment: And If I want to do a callback, What I should do?

Comment: @mac94, sorry, I don't understand the question. Please, can you explain what do you want to obtain?

Comment: I would like to replace the echo and to do a callback. In my batch file call to `:end`.

Comment: And if I use with `/d -1` I will check if the file has more than one day.

Comment: @mac94, you can't do it. The code is running in a separate `cmd` instance that knows nothing about the target label in the current batch file. Maybe there are other solutions, but comments are not a good place to include requirements and expose solutions. Can you start a new question?

Comment: I would like something like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/03/10334560.aspx

Comment: @mac94, but, what do you need? Do you need to call the subroutine passing some information (if yes, what information) to the subroutine? Or do you want to only check if a file matching the requirements is found? or ....?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that forfiles requires a **directory** as parameter. You are giving it a **file** instead. This won't work.

Instead you should do this:

```
FOR %%a in (C:\Backups\TEST.bak) DO SET FileDate=%~ta
```

This will store the file's modifed date in `%FileDate%`.

Comment: Sorry, the `:` from the path was in my code, but not in the post.

Comment: I want to use the `forfiles` because with that I can check if the file has more than one day.